# What is a symbolic differentiation of simple arithmetic expressions?

Tags: arithmetic

I am making some exercises in my programming book and one is the following:

Perform symbolic differentations of simple arithmetic expressions with respect to a single variable.

Can somebody explain this to me and perhaps give me some examples?

Comment: I don't know if this helps you, but for example one can define the derivative of a polynomial without caring from what field the coefficients come from and what kind of function it defines, simply applying the usual rules. In other words, to differentiate can be an algebraic process, without any reference to steepness of curves and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me that the question may have in mind functions involving the 4 basic arithmetic operations, i.e. addition, subtraction, multiplication and division, for 2 different functions of some variable, x.

For example, if we have :

$$ y = f(u, v) $$ where $u \equiv u(x)$  and $v \equiv v(x)$ .

1. $$y  =  u(x)  +  v(x)$$   $$ \frac{dy}{dx}  =  u'(x) + v'(x)  $$
2. $$y  =  u(x)  -  v(x)$$   $$ \frac{dy}{dx}  =  u'(x) - v'(x)  $$
3. $$y  =  u(x) * v(x)$$     $$ \frac{dy}{dx}  =  u(x) * v'(x) + v(x) * u'(x)$$
4. $$y  =  u(x) / v(x)$$      $$ \frac{dy}{dx} =  \frac{v(x) * u'(x) - u(x) * v'(x)}{v(x)^2}$$

But I'm not sure what you mean by "in my programming book" . . .

Are you doing these as a C++/Java programming exercise ?
Are you writing method code for evaluating $ \frac{dy}{dx} $ for simple expression functions so that you can then more easily obtain $ \frac{dy}{dx} $ for more complex functions if they can be resolved into arithmetic expressions of simpler ones ?

Comment: It is a book about F# (Programming Language Concepts from Peter Sestoft).

Comment: Okay. I just had a look into the first pages of that book on Amazon. As F# is a functional language resolving higher order expressions into low-order ones, we might be on the right track here. Seems like an interesting book.